# Show combobox's items as a custom node in tornadofx

Tags: kotlin, combobox, tornadofx

When use a node to show combobox's items only display the fisrt item I select.

```
val sspSelected = SimpleStringProperty()

val myItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Item 1", "Item 2","Item 3")
combobox<String>(sspSelected){
    items = myItems
    cellFormat {
        graphic = cache{
            label(it)
        }
    }
}
label(sspSelected)
```

[No selected item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsxht.jpg)

[First item selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGarV.jpg)

[Third item selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arY7j.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `cache` without supplying a cache key, so the graphic node for the cell is calculated from the first value it sees. Simply supply a unique id, in this case the string value as a cache key:

```
graphic = cache(it) {
    label(it)
}
```